# How to customize the order of the legend seperetly from the order of the bars in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a stacked bar graph which displays the response rate of subjects to a specific Topic presented to them (Topics 1 to 11). I need the stacked bars to go through "Not at all", "Somewhat" to "Very much so", like they are below. But I need the graph legend to go in reverse, where the "Very much" so label is the most bottom right, and the "Not at all" label is the most top left one. How can I do that?

[image]

Here is my code

```
graph <- ggplot(df, aes(x= Xfield, y= Yfield, fill= factor(Fillfield, levels = c("Very much so","Somewhat","Not at all") ))) +
geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") +
geom_text(aes(label= percentage_title ), position =position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) + 
scale_fill_discrete(name = "Score") +
theme(legend.position="bottom") +
labs( y ="Percentage", x ="Topic", fill=NULL, title= "Clinical Reasoning ...")+
coord_flip() + 
guides(fill=guide_legend(nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)) +
bar_3pt_scale <- scale_fill_manual(values = c("Very much so" = "purple3", "Somewhat" = "lightgreen", "Not at all" = "orange"))
```

How would I go around doing so? Would I need to develop a second scale? How can I assure that the legend scale does not interfere with the order shown in the stacked bar graph?

Comment: Set `reverse = TRUE` in `guide_legend`

Comment: Yup, that did it. I'm shocked how simple it all turned out to be. Thank you very much!